# JAXB multiple namespaces with same prefix

Tags: java, jaxb, java-8

This is my first question on StackOverflow in general, so please bear with me.

I have an issue with marshalling XML that uses the default prefix for different namespaces. Each element that uses the default prefix should specify its namespace in its opening tag. An example what I'm trying to achieve would be something like this (simplified):

```
<parent xmlns="parentNamespace" xmlns:cd1="child1Namespace">
    <cd1:child1/>
    <child2 xmlns="child2Namespace">
        ...
    </child2>
    <child3 xmlns="child3Namespace">
        ...
    </child3>
</parent>
```

I have tried setting namespaces prefixes in `package-info.java` of the object I'm trying to marshall using annotations like this:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "parentNamespace",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns = {
        @XmlNs(prefix="",parentNamespace"),
        @XmlNs(prefix="cd1", namespaceURI="child1Namespace"),
        @XmlNs(prefix="", namespaceURI="child2Namespace"),
        @XmlNs(prefix="", namespaceURI="child3Namespace")
    }
)
```

But the end result is something like this:

```
<ns1:parent xmlns:ns1="parentNamespace" xmlns:cd1="child1Namespace" xmlns="child2Namespace xmlns:ns2="child3Namespace"<
    <cd1:child1/>
    <child2>
        ...
    </child2>
    <ns2:child3>
        ...
    </ns2:child3>
</ns1:parent>
```

Which really is a valid XML, but unfortunately for reasons that are outside my control isn't good enough (doesn't pass validation). Also note that solution using Java 8 is highly preferable as I wouldn't want to mess with `NamespacePrefixMapper` if at all possible (if it even works).

So the question is: **Is it possible to generate XML using JAXB that uses same prefix for multiple namespaces and how?**